# Animate parent VC object from a child VC

Tags: ios, swift, parent-child

Is it possible to animate views of a parent VC in Swift?

I've got a root/master VC with a UIView which I'm using as a sort of a UITabBarController, so the rest of my 4 main VCs are children of the root.

On some of the child VCs, I have subviews that should take up the whole screen, without seeing the custom tab bar (UIView) from the root VC, but it still floats above.

I would like to have it slide off the screen via Y axis whenever I open the fullscreen subviews, but **I can't seem to access or manipulate the root VCs properties as it returns nil on runtime.**

Here's the custom tab bar root VC so you can understand the structure of the code:

```
class RootVC: UIViewController {

    //This is where we pull all of our content from other VCs
    //when a tab bar button is selected
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    //The custom tab bar itself with an array of button outlets
    @IBOutlet public weak var customTabBarContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var tabBarButtons: [UIButton]!

    //4 main view VCs that are reflected in the tab bar
    public var mapVC: UIViewController!
    public var favoritesVC: UIViewController!
    public var chatVC: UIViewController!
    public var profileVC: UIViewController!

    //Array for the VCs above
    public var viewControllers: [UIViewController]!

    //Index of the selected button determend by their tags
    public var selectedIndex: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var loadingLogo: UIImageView!

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        //Populating viewControllers array with
        //initiated VCs in Main storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        mapVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapVC")
        favoritesVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FavoritesVC")
        chatVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatVC")
        profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC")
        viewControllers = [mapVC, favoritesVC, chatVC, profileVC]

        //Custom tab bar + buttons visual properties
            customTabBarContainer.layer.cornerRadius = customTabBarContainer.frame.height / 2
            customTabBarContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            customTabBarContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
            customTabBarContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 10
            customTabBarContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
            tabBarButtons[0].imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            tabBarButtons[1].imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            tabBarButtons[2].imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            tabBarButtons[3].imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    }


    override public func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadingLogo.popOut()
        //Loads the initial VC
        contentView.addSubview(mapVC.view)
        mapVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        mapVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        customTabBarContainer.isHidden = false
        //Selects the inital home button
        tabBarButtons[0].isSelected = true
    }


    @IBAction func didTabButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //Keeps a track of which bar button is selected
        let previousIndex = selectedIndex
        selectedIndex = sender.tag

        //Deselects the previous bar button
        tabBarButtons[previousIndex].isSelected = false

        //Removes the previous VC
        let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]
        previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

        print("switced to \(viewControllers[selectedIndex])")

        //Selects the tapped bar button
        tabBarButtons[selectedIndex].isSelected = true
        tabBarButtons[selectedIndex].popIn()

        //Brings up the selected VC
        let nextVC = viewControllers[selectedIndex]
        contentView.addSubview(nextVC.view)
        nextVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        nextVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }
}
```

And here's the code I'm trying to use to manipulate the customTabBarContainer from a child of the MapVC:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {

        let root = self.parent?.parent as! RootVC
        root.customTabBarContainer.frame.origin.y -= root.customTabBarContainer.frame.height

    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out an answer, just in case anyone else encounters a similar problem. It will not take you to the VCs immediate parent, but instead, to its most distant ancestor, which solves my particular problem in this case.

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let rootVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! RootVC
    rootVC.customTabBarContainer.isHidden = true
```

Comment: I'm able to manipulate the RootVCs subviews from a grandchild VC

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to access the parent of the parent then?

```
self.parent?.parent as RootVC
```

assuming you are using an extension like this one to find your parentVC:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if parentResponder is UIViewController {
                return parentResponder as! UIViewController!
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

you should be able to access parent via

```
let root = self.parentViewController as! RootVC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was assuming I might be able to access the parent of my parent directly like this. I also implemented your extension, but instead of nil, it now gives me `Could not cast value of type Project.CurrentVC to Project.RootVC` when I'm trying to access it, regardless of whether I try the direct parent or the RootVC.